# Count and then group duplicate values inside an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-03-10
            [booked] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-03-10
            [booked] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-03-12
            [booked] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [date] => 2016-03-12
            [booked] => 1
        )
)
```

What I want to do is create a new array in the following format:

```
Array
(
        [0] => Array (

            (
                [date] => 2016-03-10
                [allgames] => 2
                [booked] => 2
            )
        [1] => Array (

            (
                [date] => 2016-03-12
                [allgames] => 2
                [booked] => 1
            )
)
```

So basically I am grouping the dates together, counting how many times they appear in the original array and how many of them have been "booked". But, I can't seem to get it right and I'm unsure as to how I can make the second array happen.

How would I do this?

Comment: did you tried anything? if yes show us?

Comment: Could you show your SQL query? That'd be easier.

Comment: `SELECT  date, COUNT(booked) as booked from <table name> GROUP BY date;`

Comment: in your desired array `[allgames] => 2` is there? from where you are getting this? because in your original array no where it is.

Comment: @Anant read the question. your query is wrong. allagmes is booked in your query, booked is count of booked=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Init new array, check each item of original array and increment `booked` and `allgames`, using `date` as new array key. At the end use `array_values` to remove date keys.

```
$result = array();
foreach( $array as $key => $val )
{
    if( !isset( $result[ $val['date'] ] ) )
    {
        $result[ $val['date'] ] = array
        (
            'date' => $val['date'],
            'booked' => 0,
            'allgames' => 0
        );
    }
    $result[ $val['date'] ]['allgames']++;
    if( $val['booked'] ) $result[ $val['date'] ]['booked']++;
}

$result = array_values( $result );
```

<kbd>**[3v4l.org demo](https://3v4l.org/eduCu)**</kbd>

As per comments, if your array come from a database query, you can obtain same result directly from mySQL query.

**Edit:**

I have intended `booked` key as True/False (0/1), but — if it can have any integer — you have to modify above code in this way:

```
    if( $val['booked'] ) $result[ $val['date'] ]['booked'] += $val['booked'];
```

Concerning `allgames` key, I think they have to remain untouched (= total records), otherwise its total is not coherent.

Comment: If the booked value is set to more than 1 that won't work.

Comment: @JazzCat  Yes, but this is not in question example. I have intended booked as 1/0 (True/false), otherwise why there are multiple dates? But maybe you are right, it's totally possible. I'll update my answer soon. Thank you for the point.

Answer (score 1):

You should really try to solve this with just the SQL-query.

```
<?php
$array = [
    [
        "date" => '2016-03-10',
        "booked" => 1
    ],
    [
        "date" => '2016-03-10',
        "booked" => 1
    ],
    [
        "date"=> '2016-03-12',
        "booked" => null
    ],
    [
        "date" => '2016-03-12',
        "booked" => 1
    ]
];
```

Recursive function sets the new array with dates as array-keys, just because i felt playing around with recursion.

```
function groupMatchingDates($arr, $newarr = []) {
    if(empty($arr)) {
        return array_values($newarr);
    } else {
        $newArrayItem = array_shift($arr);

        if(!isset($newarr[$newArrayItem['date']])) {
            $newarr[$newArrayItem['date']] = [
                'allgames' => 1,
                'date' => $newArrayItem['date'],
                'booked' => $newArrayItem['booked']
            ];
        } else {
            $newarr[$newArrayItem['date']]['allgames']++;
            $newarr[$newArrayItem['date']]['booked'] += $newArrayItem['booked'];
        }

        return groupMatchingDates($arr, $newarr);
    }
}
```

> $newArr = groupMatchingDates($array);
>
> var_dump($newArr);

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["allgames"]=>
    int(2)
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2016-03-10"
    ["booked"]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["allgames"]=>
    int(2)
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "2016-03-12"
    ["booked"]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
```